# Visual Studio Codes cmd working different to external cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, cmd, path

[image]
Error (Translated): The command "ffplay" is either misspelled or
could not be found.

I have the newest version of vsc installed and the path for the cmd is set to the original path "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe". Both terminals have the same path.
Typing in 'python' works on both terminals, while plenty of other commands only work in the external cmd.
Why am i getting this error?

This problem also prevents me from using the module subprocess as every command is just 'not found'.

Comment: The reason is most likely that __local__ `PATH` is different in Visual Studio environment in comparison to standard command process environment. Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) Please take care also for __reason 6__.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your terminal window has a specific title, which means that you are not using the system default terminal. If you want to use the same environment variable in vscode, a common practice is to start vscode from that terminal, and the vscode that starts this way inherits its environment variable. Enter "code" in the terminal prompt and return to start vscode

Comment: Is there a way to automatically perform this, or set it somewhere in the settings? Because typing in 'code' everytime I open Visual Studio Code in the Terminal is tedious.